# Why do I get 'data2' has not been initiliazed error here?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-http

It makes no sense at this code. I am trying to grab some strings from the ALREADY INITIALIZED from the futurebuilder data, but can't do so. It gives me the data2 has not been initialized error. Here is data and data2, they are almost similiar, data works fine but data2 doesn't. Why is that?

```
late List<Album> data;
late List<String> data2;
```

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const List<String> list = <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];
Future<List<Album>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/fluttirci/testJson/db'));

  print(response);
  Map<String, dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return (userMap['employees'] as List)
        .map((e) => Album.fromJson(e))
        .toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album(this.userId, this.id, this.title);

  Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : userId = json['userId'],
        id = json['id'],
        title = json['title'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'userId': userId,
        'id': id,
        'title': title,
      };
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;
  late Future<List<Album>> user;
  late List<Album> data;
  late List<String> data2;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: const DropdownButtonExample(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<List<Album>>(
              future: user,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  data = snapshot.data ?? [];
                  print('${data[4].title}');

                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      data2[index] = data[index].title;
                      return Column(children: [
                        Text(data[index].title ?? ""),
                      ]);
                    },
                    itemCount: data.length,
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
                return Center(
                  child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DropdownButtonApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DropdownButtonApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('DropdownButton Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: DropdownButtonExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DropdownButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownButtonExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<DropdownButtonExample> createState() => _DropdownButtonExampleState();
}

class _DropdownButtonExampleState extends State<DropdownButtonExample> {
  String dropdownValue = list.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        // This is called when the user selects an item.
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = value!;
        });
      },
      items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have not shown any code that initializes `data2`. You generally should avoid using `late` when possible anyway. `late` should be a last resort.  In your case, you could just do `List<Album> data = [];` and `List<String> data2 = [];` and avoid initialization problems entirely.

Comment: Okay, I initiliazed as you said like data2= []; but now it says RangeError(index):Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 I think it doesn't get the data. Why? data[index].title is actually string, it should of worked :(

Comment: where are you providing/assigining values in your data2? @craghack

Comment: I am providing simple strings, such as names. Nothing else. However the method the other guy below suggested just worked. So thank you for helping anyway :)

Comment: Yet I am curious to listen if you have any alternative methods either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `RangeError` issue, your `data2` is `empty` so you can search for `index` and pass your value to it, just add your string to it normally it will put that in right index, so change your listview's builder to this:

```
return ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      data2.add(data[index].title);//<--- change this
      return Column(children: [
        Text(data[index].title ?? ""),
      ]);
    },
    itemCount: data.length,
  );
```

Comment: WOW that worked! Thank you mate. But curious why my method didn't work? Am I too C++ minded for flutter?

Comment: @craghack As has been pointed out several times, your attempts read from `data2` without filling it with any elements.  That has nothing to do with C++ vs. Dart; accessing elements from an empty C++ `std::vector` would have the same problem.

Comment: But yet, print('${data[4].title}'); brings out something. How come it is empty? It isn' really empty?

Comment: you are using `data`, not `data2` to get that title. @craghack